# CameraRoll: GetPhotos - how to get the file:// url instead of content://

Tags: react-native, filesystems, expo

I am using getPhotos through CameraRoll in react-native with expo. The files loaded was using content:// instead of file:// how to read the content:// data using FileSystem. I wanted to read the file into base64. Is there a way to get file uri instead the content://

I tried not to detach the expo to use react-native-fs. Is there any other way?

Comment: you can use ImagePicker `https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/`

Comment: image picker can only allow to receive one image at a time.